# Yii - find latest user's comment

Tags: mysql, yii

I have a table name `Comment` containing fields `id, userid, content, posteddate`.

How could I find the most recent comment of user (i.e. `id = 10`) in this table?

Comment: In the basic instance by using [`findByAttributes`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#findByAttributes-detail). Did you try that?

Comment: I got this command. But I can't find the condition of "lastest".

Comment: `order by posteddate DESC` and `limit 1` will get you the last posted comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$Criteria->condition = "id = 10";
$Criteria->order = "posteddate desc";

$Comment = Comment::model()->find($Criteria);
```

Comment: This might return a multidimentional array of record. Is there any other methods that return an associative array? Thank you.

Comment: sorry you are right, it should have been `find` insteaed of `findAll`. this will return only 1 result.

Answer (score 1):

```
$model = Comment::model();
$attributes = ['userid' => 10];
$condition = ['order' => 'posteddate DESC', 'limit' => 1];

$result = $model->findByAttributes($attributes, $condition);
```